# Algorithm(s) to use to generate melodies?

Tags: algorithm

I am working at a small program to generate random melodies. So far I have an array of notes with their frequencies, the program picks a random element from the array and plays its frequency. The problem is that the melody "sounds bad": as if you sat in front of the piano and played random keys. I need an algorithm to generate a melody, with frequencies and timings and so on. I don't need anything elaborate, just make a melody that sounds good.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Algorithmic composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_composition)

Comment: @gtgaxiola: Yeah, but it's quite obvious that choosing frequencies completely at random will not produce results that most people will consider aesthetic.

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm just saying since Algorithmic composition is not deemed "good" in a popular sense. 12 tone technique is a lovely process but a mediocre end result.

Comment: @NiklasB. I need practical examples, or at least a guideline (like, "you might want to try parabolas").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use existing music (MIDI?) to train a Markov model or [Markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain)
. You may want to transpose the input to the same key(s) e.g. C major, A minor. The pitch*duration will probably have to be encoded (enumerated) into a single dimension (x*7*5, or x*12*5) . [x := number of octaves in your input range, 5=duration, 1 downto 1/16th ]
  Extra bonus for loops and variations, but that will be much harder...

Comment: Explaining: Google is your friend. "writing some code" Maybe http://sourceforge.net/projects/wakkerbot/ ??

Answer (score 3):

If you want the music to be "airy" and never dissonant then use Pentatonic Scales (i.e Like playing the black keys of the piano)

For example:
Pitch Selection:

`C#,D#,F#,G# or A#`

Pitch Range:
3 to 5 Octaves  (since an Octave up or down is basically doubling or halving the frequency of your base frequency)

Note Duration:

Range from `16th` to `Whole Note`

Comment: Quite what I was looking for: a simple system to generate a never-dissonant melody. [Although the part on the "Note duration" was quite obvious, like "pick a random value from the common (1/16, 1/16 and its half, 1/8, 1/8 and its half...)]

Answer (score 1):

Others have tried this. You might like to read the article 'Music and Fractal Landscapes' by Richard MacDuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing notes from the same scale :) C major, D minor or so ;)
Or even the pentatonic.

Answer (score 0):

import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
class Me{
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int fij=128; int tw=64; int fd=2048; 
     int secs=128; String fo="Me.wav"; int ho=8;
     if(args.length==5){ fij=4*Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
          tw=4*Integer.parseInt(args[1]); fd=4*Integer.parseInt(args[2]); 
          ho=4+Integer.parseInt(args[3]); fo=args[4]; 
     }          
     double[] pcm_datadrd = new double[44100*secs];
     double[] pcm_datadr = new double[44100];
     for (int i=0; i<pcm_datadr.length; i++) {
          pcm_datadr[i]=( 64*Math.sin((i/1837.5*(i*i/128))*Math.PI*2)/(1+(Math.cos((4096) +64))+(i/256)) );
     }
     for(int x=0;x<(secs-1);x++){
     for (int i=0; i<pcm_datadr.length; i++) {
          pcm_datadrd[((int)(44100*x)+i)] = (double)
          ( 128*Math.sin((i/1837.5*(i*i/256))*Math.PI*2)/(1+(Math.cos((4096) +64))+((double)i/256)) );
          }     
     }
     byte[] pcm_data = new byte[44100*secs];
     for (int i=0; i<pcm_data.length; i++) {    
          double fup=1+(fij*i/pcm_data.length);
          pcm_data[i]=(byte)(pcm_datadrd[i]+(64*Math.sin((i/tw*fup*Math.cos(3+(i/fd))))+
          32*Math.sin(5+(i/ho*fd)*Math.cos(i/(fd+tw)))));
     }
     AudioFormat frmt = new AudioFormat(44100, 8, 1, true, true);
     AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream( 
          new ByteArrayInputStream(pcm_data), frmt,  pcm_data.length / frmt.getFrameSize()
     );
     try {
     AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File(fo));
     }catch(Exception e) {    e.printStackTrace(); }       
     }
}

Comment: God bless the Slingerland

Answer (score -1):

> ABBA 'k vind't voor de kleintjes zielig die me laten MMA je, je
>   vergeetk wat en huilt ook weet ik tranen

It's better not randomly create a block A of random notes and B random notes and Do (ABBA)+ or (AB)AB* but better apply the concept of Quantum Theory (everything in nature interacts, like our house-rules here see are applied in ervery house in the world), as you now understand.

So like, a cellular automata, 'game of life' you can, per step, play your 'true' notes, letting the 'y-axis' the note number and (please count) the duration of a note (adjacing trues along the 'x-axis')

Example of this sound for randomness sake:
http://simple.ogena.net/Steel_Drum-Slap_Bas.mp3
from generated source:
http://simple.ogena.net/Steel_Drum-Slap_Bas.mid

Comment: Could you maybe clean up your answer a bit? It's hard to understand what you mean exactly.